# Remove extra space around QWizardPage inside QWizard

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, wizard

I'm writing some wizard using Qt 5.2.1 under Ubuntu 13.10. I have header image and want to show it at the top of almost all wizard pages. So i opened QtDesigned, created new QWizardPage form and result looks like (conceptually):

[image: QWizardPage in QtDesigner]

Blue area at the top is my header image. It should takes all top area, from (0,0) to (window.width, image.height).

Then i just add this page to QWizard:

```
SetupWizard::SetupWizard(QWidget * parent) : QWizard(parent) {
    welcomePage_ = new SetupWizardWelcomePage(this);
    setPage(WELCOME_PAGE, welcomePage_);
    ...
```

And result is:

[image: QWizardPage in running app]

As you can see there are small margins at left, right and top of my header image. I've tried to change styling of QWizard, set fixed size and play with geometry - nothing helps me. Seems like this spacing is defined inside QWizard class, but i'm not sure about it.

So am i able to show header without spacing using QWizard? Or i have to create my own Wizard class?

Comment: How did you change styling of QWizard ? Take a look here http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq20-qss.html , in "The Box Model" chapter ;)

Comment: By styling QWizard i meant Wizard Style option, which set by setWizardStyle(WizardStyle style) and can be ClassicStyle, ModernStyle, MacStyle, AeroStyle and NStyles. Setting margin and padding to 0 in style sheets of QWizard won't help.

Comment: To my mind, you have to check margin and padding from both of your widgets (parents and son), not just QWizard.

Comment: Thanks for idea, but this didn't help. I've wrote:
"margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;"

Comment: @serg.v.gusev did you solve this in the end?

Comment: @Zmey unfortunately no

Answer (score 1):

Header's banner and logo can be set using

```
setPixmap(QWizard::BannerPixmap, bannerPixmap);
setPixmap(QWizard::LogoPixmap, logoPixmap);
```

However, wizard window will no longer be resizable horizontally. Also, I wanted to customize header even more, so I added a custom header to QWizardPage instead. This  produced white border around the page which you also observed.

Border can be removed with this hack in QWizard's constructor:

```
QWidget *flickerWidget = (QWidget *)(children()[0]);
flickerWidget->layout()->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

But it's not practical as separator above buttons will also lose padding plus there will be no padding around buttons.

What I done in the end is:

- Created a new widget inherited from QDialog with QVBoxLayout layout in which I put my custom header widget + QWizard instance.
- Connected to wizard's currentIdChanged(int) signal and updated custom header's title and subtitle in signal's handler.
- If ESC was pressed, wizard widget destroyed itself so I routed it's finished() signal to my dialog's done() to close it as well:

`connect(m_wizard, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(done(int)));`

*Optional:* I also made a custom subclass of QWizardPage in which I overridden setTitle and setSubTitle and didn't call parent's ones so original header would not be visible. In currentIdChanged() handler, I queried page subclass for title/subtitle and set it in custom header.

I also used `setWizardStyle(QWizard::ClassicStyle)` so wizard would have appropriate background color / padding without it's native title/subtitle. ModernStyle used to produce weird colors when title wasn't set.

It works in the end, but maybe creating the wizard from scratch would be easier.